# How should errors be handled when using the Ember.js Data RESTAdapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

ember-data.js: https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/0396411e39df96c8506de3182c81414c1d0eb981

In short, when there is an error, I want to display error messages in the view, and then the user can 1) cancel, which will rollback the transaction 2) correct the input errors and successfully commit the transaction, passing the validations on the server.

Below is a code snippet from the source. It doesn't include an error callback.

```
updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
  var id = get(record, 'id');
  var root = this.rootForType(type);

  var data = {};
  data[root] = this.toJSON(record);

  this.ajax(this.buildURL(root, id), "PUT", {
    data: data,
    context: this,
    success: function(json) {
      this.didUpdateRecord(store, type, record, json);
    }
  });
},
```

Overall, what is the flow of receiving an error from the server and updating the view? It seems that an error callback should put the model in an `isError` state, and then the view can display the appropriate messages. Also, the transaction should stay dirty. That way, the transaction can use `rollback`.

It seems that using `store.recordWasInvalid` is going in the right direction, though.

Comment: There is not yet a complete mechanism for handling errors, see https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/376/, perhaps you will find what you want.

Comment: Yes, the lack of error handling is surprising, but it's nice that there's no error handling as opposed to a naive implementation that will change later. I've written my recent Ember app to avoid server errors by performing some validations on the client-side, before doing `App.store.commit()`.

Answer (score 42):

This weekend I was trying to figure the same thing out. Going off what Luke said, I took a closer look at the ember-data source for the [latest commit](https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/23d40fb72fd600c39f10e9899e545ce8d78dd076/) (Dec 11).

**TLDR; to handle ember-data update/create errors, simply define `becameError()` and `becameInvalid(errors)` on your `DS.Model` instance. The cascade triggered by the RESTadapter's AJAX error callback will eventually call these functions you define.**

Example:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr "string"
  body: DS.attr "string"

  becameError: ->
    # handle error case here
    alert 'there was an error!'

  becameInvalid: (errors) ->
    # record was invalid
    alert "Record was invalid because: #{errors}"
```

Here's the full walk through the source:

In the REST adapter, the AJAX callback error function is given [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/23d40fb72fd600c39f10e9899e545ce8d78dd076/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L107-L109):

```
   this.ajax(this.buildURL(root, id), "PUT", {
      data: data,
      context: this,
      success: function(json) {
        Ember.run(this, function(){
          this.didUpdateRecord(store, type, record, json);
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        this.didError(store, type, record, xhr);
      }
    });
```

didError is defined [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/23d40fb72fd600c39f10e9899e545ce8d78dd076/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L304-L311) and it in turn calls the store's recordWasInvalid or recordWasError depending on the response:

```
  didError: function(store, type, record, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 422) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      store.recordWasInvalid(record, data['errors']);
    } else {
      store.recordWasError(record);
    }
  },
```

In turn, `store.recordWasInvalid` and `store.recordWasError` (defined [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/23d40fb72fd600c39f10e9899e545ce8d78dd076/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L932-L945)) call the record (a DS.Model)'s handlers. In the invalid case, it passes along error messages from the adapter as an argument.

```
 recordWasInvalid: function(record, errors) {
    record.adapterDidInvalidate(errors);
  },

  recordWasError: function(record) {
    record.adapterDidError();
  },
```

`DS.Model.adapterDidInvalidate` and `adapterDidError` (defined [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/23d40fb72fd600c39f10e9899e545ce8d78dd076/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L305-L311)) simply `send('becameInvalid', errors)` or `send('becameError')` which finally leads us to the handlers [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/23d40fb72fd600c39f10e9899e545ce8d78dd076/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js#L40-L45):

```
  didLoad: Ember.K,
  didUpdate: Ember.K,
  didCreate: Ember.K,
  didDelete: Ember.K,
  becameInvalid: Ember.K,
  becameError: Ember.K,
```

(Ember.K is just a dummy function for returning `this`. See [here](http://code418.com/blog/2012/03/08/useful-emberjs-functions/))

So, the conclusion is, you simply need to define functions for `becameInvalid` and `becameError` on your model to handle these cases.

Hope this helps someone else; the docs certainly don't reflect this right now.

Comment: You can also use a onetime callback by adding `model.one('becameInvalid', function() { // error handling here })` before you commit the transaction, if you want to handle errors differently depending on the context.

Comment: Great explanation here. The only thing this doesn't cover is how to propagate the error to the model so the Ember.Route's error event can act accordingly. The user may have navigated to a ID that doesn't exist, in which case you want to give them the right error. So a combination of this and the answer above might make sense.

Comment: STALE: The check for 422 status seems to have been moved to the active_model_adapter: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/7af6fcb070deb374ca12a96d5a7e5344f8c8a1b9/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_adapter.js#L99

Comment: The json hash retrieved from the server must have "errors" key with errors in it. Otherwise an error will be raised.

Answer (score 8):

`DS.RESTAdapter` just got a bit more error handling in [this commit](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/36a70c9839c9807248856ce2e25959bf80d6b941) but we are still not yet at a point where we have a great recommendation for error handling.

If you are ambitious/crazy enough to put apps in production today with ember-data (as I have been!), it is best to make sure that the likelihood of failures in your API is extremely low. i.e. validate your data client-side.

Hopefully, we can update this question with a much better answer in the coming months.

Comment: What's the state of error handling in Ember.Data today?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into such a situation, not sure if this is already explained anywhere.

I am using:

```
Em.VERSION : 1.0.0
DS.VERSION : "1.0.0-beta.6"
Ember Validations (dockyard) : Version: 1.0.0.beta.1
Ember I18n
```

The model was initially mixedin with Validation mixin.

```
App.Order = DS.Model.extend(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
.....
someAttribute : DS.attr('string'),
/* Client side input validation with ember-validations */
validations : {
    someAttribute : {
        presence : {
            message : Ember.I18n.t('translations.someAttributeInputError')
        }
    }
}
});
```

In the template, corresponding handlebars is added. (note that ember validations will automatically add errors to `model.errors.<attribute>` in case of input validations, I will be using same trade-off in server validations as well)

```
<p>{{t 'translations.myString'}}<br>
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="attributeName"}}
  {{#if model.errors.attributeName.length}}<small class="error">{{model.errors.attributeName}}</small>{{/if}}
</p
```

Now, we will be saving the `Order`

```
App.get('order').save().then(function () {
  //move to next state?
}, function(xhr){
  var errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
  for(var error in errors){ //this loop is for I18n
    errors[error] = Ember.I18n.t(errors[error]);
  }
  controller.get('model').set('errors', errors); //this will overwrite current errors if any
});
```

Now if there is some validation error thrown from server, the returned packet being used is

```
{"errors":{"attributeName1":"translations.attributeNameEror",
 "another":"translations.anotherError"}}

status : 422
```

It is important to use status **422**

So this way, your attribute(s) can be validated client side and again on server side.

Disclaimer : I am not sure if this is the best way!

Answer (score 2):

Since there's currently no good solution in stock Ember-Data, I made my own solution by adding an `apiErrors` property to DS.Model and then in my RestAdapter subclass (I already needed my own) I added error callbacks to the Ajax calls for `createRecord` and `updateRecord` that save the errors and put the model in the "invalid" state, which is supposed to mean client-side or server-side validations failed.

Here's the code snippets:

This can go in application.js or some other top-level file:

```
DS.Model.reopen({
  // Added for better error handling on create/update
  apiErrors: null
});
```

This goes in the error callbacks for `createRecord` and `updateRecord` in a RestAdapter subclass:

```
error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    errors = null;
    try {
        errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).errors;
    } catch(e){} //ignore parse error
    if(errors) {
        record.set('apiErrors',errors);
    }
    record.send('becameInvalid');
}
```