# Detecting when Ember.Data request fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app which allows users to submit a post to Twitter. It's using Ember.Data with a Django Rest Framework back end. A user posts a Message, which goes to the server, then submits to Twitter, then returns the response back to the client. That part all works fine but I want to build in code to manage the times when the request fails, either on our server or on the request to Twitter.

I've found documentation on an [isError state](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/states.js#L224) for Models but I'm not sure if this is the correct property I'm looking for.

Here's the code I'm currently implementing:

```
saveMessage: function(text, postingWindow){
    var acct = Social.Account.find(this.get("id")),
        msg = Social.store.createRecord(
                  Social.Message,
                  {
                      text: text,
                      account: acct,
                      created: new Date()
                  }
              );

    acct.get("messages").addObject(msg);
    Social.store.commit();
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is to hold off displaying the message in the UI until I know I have success from the user. But on the flip side I don't want to wait forever if I can get an error state right away.

Comment: if you guys are using the ember-data django rest framework adapter could you verify you pulled in the latest pull request (around error handling specifically) https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter/commits/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my answer here: [How should errors be handled when using the Ember.js Data RESTAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968829/how-should-errors-be-handled-when-using-the-ember-js-data-restadapter/13845348#13845348)

Basically, you can override the callbacks `becameError` and `becameInvalid` on a DS.Model subclass. There are other Model lifecycle callbacks that you can hook into. See here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/

Comment: Sherwin...that doesn't seem to work. According to some of the peeps in the Ember chat room, that might be broken at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, that might be the case. I'm using an older build of ember -- what version are you using?

Comment: Ember data rev 11 and Ember 1.0.0-rc.1

Comment: For me didDelete, becameError, becameInvalid not working, ember-data revision 12, ember rc3. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
AdminApp.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: '',
    host: 'http://localhost/myroomplan_wp/index.php/wp-json',
    ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```