# handle errors from the rest adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using ember-data, and want to trap and display any errors returned by the rest adapter. I looked at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968829/how-should-errors-be-handled-when-using-the-ember-js-data-restadapter)

I added the following code to my model definition:

```
 becameInvalid: function(errors) {
        alert ("here" + errors);
    },
```

and the rest adapter returns a 422 (Unprocessable Entity) code

however, the alert doesn't show. Am I missing something, or just being a real newbie numpty?

**update #1:**

making some progress. The rest server returns the following Json:

```
{"errors":{ "lastName": ["LastName cannot be blank"] }}
```

the model has

```
becameInvalid: function(errors) { console.log(JSON.stringify(errors)); },
```

however, the console now has the following:

```
{"email":"jmls@foo,com","firstName":"Julian","id":"aa7c4b42-df64-8fb8-d213-0ad81‌​c9bc213","lastName":"","notes":"ccc"}
```

which seems to be the json of the record itself, not of the errors.

How can I get to the errors? I have tried

```
console.log(errors.get("errors.lastName")
```

but get undefined.

Comment: Can you show more informantion about your code, like model mapping and the returned json response?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
becameError: function(object) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your are missing something, using `becameInvalid` worked for me.

For example:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string') ,
    becameInvalid: function(errors) {        
        alert(errors.get('errors.name').join(','));
    }
});
```

**Update**

Following the suggestion of @fanta, in the commend. Maybe your problem is in the returned json, the expected is:

```
{
  errors: {
    field_a: ['error a', 'error b'],
    field_b: ['error c']
  }
}
```

Where `field_a` must be some field mapped on `DS.attr(field_a)`.

Give a look in that sample http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/8maNq/

Comment: it might be possible that he is not returning the name of the field with the error, or the name does not match the one defined in Ember Model, names should match.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `DS.rejectionHandler`:

```
DS.rejectionHandler = function(reason) {
  Ember.Logger.assert([reason, reason.message, reason.stack]);

  throw reason;
};
```

This should catch all errors from the adapter.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of ember-data from http://builds.emberjs.com/? Older versions might not have the rejection handler.

Comment: yeah, updating my app to use 1.0 beta of ember-data - will let you know what it fixes ;)